# Dependency between categorical and numerical data

Tags: python

I am analyzing a data set with categorical and numeric values. I would like to detect dependences between categorical and numeric values columns. I have encountered a suggestion to user r-factor of linear model and interpreted it as a R-square. However, after applying the r-square to my data, result does not make any sense.

Did any of you perform such analysis using any other method than r-factor?

`corr_matrix = np.corrcoef(data.x, data.y)` 
`corr = corr_matrix[0,1]`
`R_sq = corr**2`
`print(R_sq)`